Best way to exclude `null` or empty [] values from an output of a Cypher query
CONTEXT
I have setup a neo4j vector index in combination with cypher query to fetch specific nodes and and traverse through their paths to return specific data. Given this data will be passed to an LLM for summarisation, the output should be as clean as possible.
FUNCTION
def generate_employee_cypher_query(schema): fetches specific paths from entity Èmployee` by following the schema/ontology paths:
def generate_employee_cypher_query(schema):
    employee_schema = schema["Employee"]
    match_clauses = []
    return_blocks = []
    
    # Initial vector search
    base_query = """
    CALL db.index.vector.queryNodes($index_name, $n_results, $query_embedding)
    YIELD node AS employee, score
    WHERE employee:Employee AND employee.user_id = $user_id
    
    MATCH (employee)
    """
    
    # Generate MATCH clauses from schema relationships
    for rel in employee_schema["relationships"]:
        rel_type = rel["type"]
        end_node = rel["endNode"]
        cardinality = rel.get("cardinality", "0..n")  # Default to 0..n if not specified
        
        # Handle different cardinalities and relationship directions
        if rel["startNode"] == "Employee":
            # Outgoing relationship from Employee
            match_clauses.append(
                f"OPTIONAL MATCH (employee)-[{rel_type.lower()}Rel:{rel_type}]->"
                f"({rel_type.lower()}:{end_node})"
            )
            
            # Special handling for relationships with TimeFrame
            if end_node in ["Availability", "Unavailability"]:
                match_clauses.append(
                    f"OPTIONAL MATCH ({rel_type.lower()})-[:HAS_TIMEFRAME]->"
                    f"({rel_type.lower()}TimeFrame:TimeFrame)"
                )
        else:
            # Incoming relationship to Employee
            match_clauses.append(
                f"OPTIONAL MATCH ({rel_type.lower()}:{end_node})"
                f"-[{rel_type.lower()}Rel:{rel_type}]->(employee)"
            )
    
    # Generate return blocks for each relationship
    return_blocks.append("""
    employee.name AS employeeName,
    score,
    apoc.convert.toJson(
        CASE WHEN employee IS NOT NULL 
        THEN apoc.map.removeKeys(properties(employee), 
            ['embedding', 'id', 'elementId', 'user_id', 'timestamp', 'created', 'updated']
        )
        ELSE {} 
        END
    ) AS employeeJson,
    """)
    
    # Start connections array
    return_blocks.append("apoc.convert.toJson([")
    
    # Generate individual connection blocks
    connection_blocks = []
    for rel in employee_schema["relationships"]:
        rel_type = rel["type"]
        end_node = rel["endNode"]
        cardinality = rel.get("cardinality", "0..n")
        
        # Handle cardinality in return statement
        is_single = cardinality in ["1..1", "0..1"]
        collection_suffix = "[0]" if is_single else ""
        
        if end_node in ["Availability", "Unavailability"]:
            # Special handling for timeframe relationships
            connection_blocks.append(f"""{{
                type: '{rel_type}',
                {rel_type.lower()}: collect(DISTINCT CASE WHEN {rel_type.lower()} IS NOT NULL 
                    THEN {{
                        employeeName: {rel_type.lower()}.employeeName,
                        timeframe: CASE WHEN {rel_type.lower()}TimeFrame IS NOT NULL 
                            THEN {{
                                dateIndicator: {rel_type.lower()}TimeFrame.dateIndicator,
                                type: {rel_type.lower()}TimeFrame.type,
                                recurring: {rel_type.lower()}TimeFrame.recurring
                            }}
                            ELSE null 
                        END
                    }}
                    ELSE null END){collection_suffix}
            }}""")
        else:
            # Standard relationship handling
            connection_blocks.append(f"""{{
                type: '{rel_type}',
                {end_node.lower()}: collect(DISTINCT CASE WHEN {rel_type.lower()} IS NOT NULL 
                    THEN apoc.map.removeKeys(properties({rel_type.lower()}), 
                        ['embedding', 'id', 'elementId', 'user_id', 'timestamp', 'created', 'updated']
                    )
                    ELSE null END){collection_suffix}
            }}""")
    
    # Close connections array
    return_blocks.append(",\n".join(connection_blocks))
    return_blocks.append("]) AS connectionsJson")
    
    # Combine all query parts
    full_query = (
        base_query +
        "\n".join(match_clauses) +
        "\nRETURN " +
        "\n".join(return_blocks)
    )
    
    return full_query

Now, the output of this specific function can be seen in the example below:
Employee Vector Search Results:
[
  {
    "employeeName": "Emma Williams",
    "score": 0.6321649551391602,
    "employee": {
      "name": "Emma Williams",
      "email": "emma.w@hotelexample.com"
    },
    "connections": [
      {
        "contract": {
          "contractType": "Part-time"
        },
        "type": "HAS_CONTRACT_TYPE"
      },
      {
        "has_unavailability": [],
        "type": "HAS_UNAVAILABILITY"
      },
      {
        "has_availability": [
          {
            "employeeName": "Emma Williams",
            "timeframe": {
              "recurring": true,
              "dateIndicator": "Thu-Sat 16:00-00:00",
              "type": "DayOfWeek"
            }
          }
        ],
        "type": "HAS_AVAILABILITY"
      },
      {
        "team": {
          "name": "F&B"
        },
        "type": "BELONGS_TO"
      },
      {
        "education": [],
        "type": "HAS_EDUCATION"
      },
      {
        "type": "HAS_CERTIFICATION",
        "certification": [
          {
            "name": "Alcohol Service"
          },
          {
            "name": "Mixology Certificate"
          }
        ]
      },

notice in the above output the empty strings in "education": [], or "has_unavailability": [],. I want those values to not be included in the output.
thank you in advance
Manuel
I tried using CASE expressions or apoc.map.clean but did not seem to lead to the results i wanted.

While it would be possible to do that by changing your Python and Cypher code, it would be much simpler to just modify the JSON Employee Vector Search Results.
For example, here is a sample function that takes your Employee Vector Search Results and filters out, from every employee's connections list, all objects that have a type key and another key whose value is an empty list:
def filter_employee_connections(json_result):
    result = json.loads(json_result)
    for employee in result:
        employee["connections"] = [
            c for c in employee["connections"]
            if not any(isinstance(val, list) and not val for key, val in c.items() if key != "type")
        ]
    return json.dumps(result, indent=2)

The resulting JSON would look something like this:
[
  {
    "employeeName": "Emma Williams",
    "score": 0.6321649551391602,
    "employee": {
      "name": "Emma Williams",
      "email": "emma.w@hotelexample.com"
    },
    "connections": [
      {
        "contract": {
          "contractType": "Part-time"
        },
        "type": "HAS_CONTRACT_TYPE"
      },
      {
        "has_availability": [
          {
            "employeeName": "Emma Williams",
            "timeframe": {
              "recurring": true,
              "dateIndicator": "Thu-Sat 16:00-00:00",
              "type": "DayOfWeek"
            }
          }
        ],
        "type": "HAS_AVAILABILITY"
      },
      {
        "team": {
          "name": "F&B"
        },
        "type": "BELONGS_TO"
      },
      {
        "type": "HAS_CERTIFICATION",
        "certification": [
          {
            "name": "Alcohol Service"
          },
          {
            "name": "Mixology Certificate"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]


Thanks a lot for the suggestion! it was indeed much simpler to just modify the JSON Employee Vector Search and the other vector index Results
I implemented a solution that builds upon your approach while adding some additional robustness to handle different types of empty values in my Neo4j vector search results.
def filter_empty_connections(results):
"""
Filter out empty connections from vector search results across all data types
(Employee, Work, Project, WorkAllocation, WorkScheduleRule).
"""
if not results or "results" not in results:
    return results

def is_empty_value(val):
    """Check if a value is considered empty."""
    if isinstance(val, list):
        # Check if list is empty or contains only empty/null values
        return len(val) == 0 or all(is_empty_value(item) for item in val)
    if isinstance(val, dict):
        # Check if dict is empty or contains only empty/null values
        return len(val) == 0 or all(is_empty_value(v) for v in val.values())
    return val is None or val == ""

def filter_single_item(item):
    """Filter empty connections from a single item's connections array."""
    if "connections" not in item:
        return item
        
    filtered_connections = []
    for conn in item["connections"]:
        # Skip the connection if all its non-type fields are empty
        has_non_empty_value = False
        for key, val in conn.items():
            if key != "type" and not is_empty_value(val):
                has_non_empty_value = True
                break
        
        if has_non_empty_value:
            filtered_connections.append(conn)
    
    item["connections"] = filtered_connections
    return item

filtered_items = [
    filter_single_item(item) 
    for item in results["results"]
]

return {"results": filtered_items}

Then I integrated it into my index functions like this:
def employee_details_index(query, query_embedding, n_results=50):
# ... existing query execution code ...

structured_results = []
for row in results:
    employee_data = {
        "employeeName": row["employeeName"],
        "score": row["score"],
        "employee": json.loads(row["employeeJson"]),
        "connections": json.loads(row["connectionsJson"])
    }
    structured_results.append(employee_data)

# Apply filtering before returning
filtered_results = filter_empty_connections({"results": structured_results})
return filtered_results

This approach successfully removed empty connections like "education": [] and "has_unavailability": [] from the results while keeping the connection entries that had actual data.
Thank you again for pointing me in the right direction! This solution worked perfectly for my use case.
